# Java error: bad operand types for binary operator '+' and unexpected type error

Tags: java, string

Im pretty new to programming and I have a hard time finding what is wrong in this code it look like the problem is only on the end part of my code, I'm not sure if it just on the syntax? or Is there any conversions I needed to concatenate two strings? If there's not what are other methods I could use?.
The error I got is bad operand type error and unexpected type error.

### Here is my code:

```
    System.out.printf("\nName:\nName;, Age:", first_name + last_name, age);
    System.out.printf("\nBeginning Balance = %.2f\nInterest Rate = %.2f", accountBalance, interest);
    System.out.printf("\nBalance at the end of the month = $%.2f\n\nThe character that comes after the 1%s is the ASCII set is %1s", interest/100*accountBalance/12=accountBalance,(char)(letter+1));
```

Comment: Please show more code. At least the declarations of your variables.

Comment: Post your full code here, so that someone can help.

Comment: Note also that your first format string doesn't have any placeholders.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are the (declared) types of `first_name`, `last_name` and `letter`? I particularly suspect that `letter` may be a reference type to which you cannot add 1. Best [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).